# Why is $\sqrt{2}$ not in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Sorry if this is too obvious but I can't see what I'm missing. If an element $b\in B$ is the root of a polynomial $f\in A[X]$, then $b$ is integral over $B$.

$\sqrt{2}$ is a root of $f(X) = X^2 -2$, so why is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ equal to $\mathbb{Z}$? I know I must be misreading a definition but I can't see where, if anyone could point out what I'm missing that would be great.

Comment: According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element), there is no such thing as "the integral closure of a ring $A$". It is always "the integral closure of a ring $A$ in a ring $B$", where $A$ is a subring of $B$. And this integral closure contains $A$ as a subring. So the intergral closure of $\mathbb Q$ can't be $\mathbb Z$ over any subring, because $\mathbb Z$ doesn't contain $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You're right, edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: OK, so now there are only two mistakes left: (i) your first sentence should read "...then $b$ is integral over $A$"; and (ii) this (corrected) definition contains the condition $b\in B$, but $\sqrt 2$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition the ring of integers of a field is a subset of the field. $\sqrt 2$ satisfies an integral equation over $\Bbb Q$, sure, but it's not in the field. In fact, you can see from this that integral elements of a field are exactly those that satisfy integral, **linear** polynomials over the field's integer ring. (Since linear iff the constant term is in the field already).

Your question and title, in particular, don't match: integral closure and elements of a field which are integral are not the same thing, that's a question only for things which you can talk about integrality for, since while $\Bbb Z$ **is** the ring of integers for $\Bbb Q$ it is **not** the integral closure of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: isn't your definition of integral circular ?

Comment: @mercio no, I said "satisfies an **integral** equation over $\Bbb Q$," not just any polynomial.

Comment: But $q x - p = 0$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients which have solution $x = p/q$. So why not every rational number integral over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @kp9r4d "integral," not "integer."

Answer (score 2):

Proper rationals($Q-Z$) are not integral over $Z$ however $√2$ is....for the first assertion put $p/q$ as lowest terms in polynomial.